# Gulp Watch Not calling associated gulp task

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

So I'm coming back to a personal project after a (prolonged) break, and I'm getting back into the flow of things.  One thing that smacks me in the face is that my watchers aren't working.  If, for example, I call `gulp watch-for-jshint`, I expect JSHint to be changed anytime I modify a JS file -- either a root one (gulp.js) or one of my client-app ones (./client-app/js/controllers/register.js).  That's not happening.  I can see watch is starting, but it never calls JSHint when I change my files!

Anyone have any ideas what is going wrong or how to diagnose?  As far as I can tell, I have the syntax right...  And because (for testing purposes) I'm directly calling watch-for-jshint, I should be avoiding the usual pitfall of never actually calling my watcher.

Simplified gulp file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  clean = require('gulp-clean'),
  jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
  notify = require('gulp-notify'),
  watch = require('gulp-watch'),

gulp.task('jshint', function(){
  console.log("Running JSHint");
  return gulp.src(['*.js', 'client-app/**/*.js'], ['jshint'])
    .pipe(jshint({"moz":true}))
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('fail'))
    .on('error', notify.onError({ sound: "Funk" }));
});

gulp.task('watch-for-jshint', function(){
  return watch(['*.js', './client-app/**/*.js'], ['jshint']);
});
```

I've truncated a lot of extraneous tasks, but what's above should be everything relevant.

Answer (score 0):

And naturally, 5 minutes after posting I notice one difference between my syntax and what a lot of questions are using.  Most people are using `gulp.watch`, I was just following the syntax found at the [gulp-watch NPM module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch) page of using just `watch`.

Not... entirely sure why one works and the other doesn't; odd.  Seems like the new version shouldn't work, since it's not referencing the gulp-watch module.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following  line in gulp task, if it is not necessary.

.on('error', notify.onError({ sound: "Funk" }))

This makes the gulp task  stop and show error. Hence watch is also stopped.

Replace

return watch(['*.js', './client-app/**/*.js'], ['jshint']);

with

gulp.watch(['*.js', './client-app/**/*.js'], ['jshint']);